# Searching through combobox items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox with items:
`AA, BB, CC`

Then I have a DataGridView with the rows same as below:

```
Remarks
-------
 AAA
 BBB
 CCC
 DDD
```

I need to check if the selected value ing the DataGridView exists in the ComboBox Items.

I have tried this:

```
if (combobox.Items.Contains ("AAA")) {

}
```

But it always returns false even if "AAA" is on the combobox items.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by match? How these values gonna match to each other?

Comment: `comboBox.Items.Contains(selectedGridValue)`? is this wpf or windows forms?

Comment: Kindly see updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @QKWS I put up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your gridView items are:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Note that they are 3 characters each, while your `ComboBox`'s:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

While in order for you to have the following to return `true`:

```
comboBox.Items.Contains("AAA")
```

You must have **exact** item of `AAA` in your `ComboBox`. Thus, it explains why does it return `false`. To fix, your `ComboBox` must have `Items` of `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC` instead of `AA`, `BB`, and `CC`.

Additionally, note that if you use `string`, then:

```
string val = "AAA";
if (val.Contains("AA")){ //will return true
    //will be executed
}
```

But if you reverse it:

```
string val = "AA";
if (val.Contains("AAA")){ //will return false
    //will not be executed
}
```

This is because `string.Contains` will return `true` as long as there is a matching `substring` as the `Contains` argument.

**BUT**

For a collection, suppose you have `ComboBox` with the following items:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Then if you try to find:

```
if(comboBox.Items.Contains("AA")) //note that this has one less A
```

You will **not** find it. This is because for `Contains` to return `true` in the above case, the argument given (in the above case being `AA`) must match **exactly** with an element in the collection and **not** with the *substring* of the element.